# What is the JavaScript Escape code for Unicode Carriage Return?

Tags: javascript, unicode, carriage-return, unicode-escapes

If I ever need to include a **newline** in a HTML `title` attribute tooltip, I use the **HTML Escape Character** for *Carriage Return*:

- `&#013;`

---

**Example:**

- `<img src="" title="Line 1&#013;Line 2" alt="" />`

> Apparently, `&#13;` also works, so I'm unclear where I learned to include the leading zero.

---

However, inserting `&#013;` *doesn't work* when dynamically creating an HTML element in JavaScript.

**Working Example:**

*Hover over the examples below to see the difference in how the tooltips are displayed.*

```js
const myImage = document.createElement('img');
myImage.setAttribute('src', '');
myImage.setAttribute('width', '100');
myImage.setAttribute('height', '100');
myImage.setAttribute('title', 'test line 1&#13;&#13;test line 2');
myImage.setAttribute('alt', '');
document.body.appendChild(myImage);
```

```html
<img src="" width="100" height="100" title="test line 1&#013;&#013;test line 2" alt="" />
```

---

### Question:

What **JavaScript Escape** should I use instead of the **HTML Escape** `&#013;` ?

> **N.B.** Yes, I know I *can* use `\n` - but in JavaScript that represents a newline literal.
>
> In this case I simply want to include in my string the JavaScript Escape for ASCII / Unicode *Carriage Return* - basically, the JavaScript equivalent of `&#013;` in HTML.

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String#escape_sequences — `\r` or `\x0D` should do…

Comment: @Ouroborus No, a newline is different from a carriage return. Not sure it really makes a difference in OP's case; it may or it mayn't, reserving judgement on that…

Comment: @deceze - that's a great reference. Thank you. Bookmarked.

Comment: I'm shocked you've never come across it before…!?

Comment: @deceze Oh, yeah, you're right. `\n` and `&#10;` is new line or line feed, `\r` and `&#13;` is carriage return. Though they seem to do the same thing in this particular situation.

Comment: @deceze - Oh, I use MDN all the time - I meant that particular section on that page (which I didn't find in my repeated searches before posting the question above).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got it. Thanks, everyone.

The answer I was looking for is:

- `\u000D` is the JavaScript Escape equivalent of the HTML Escape `&#013;`

---

**Working Example:**

```js
const myImage = document.createElement('img');
myImage.setAttribute('src', '');
myImage.setAttribute('width', '100');
myImage.setAttribute('height', '100');
myImage.setAttribute('title', 'test line 1\u000D\u000Dtest line 2');
myImage.setAttribute('alt', '');
document.body.appendChild(myImage);
```

```html
<img src="" width="100" height="100" title="test line 1&#013;&#013;test line 2" alt="" />
```